# My enemy is frozen mid-air and doesn't move

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I think my game should be running smoothly but insted it's just frozen.  I don't really know where to start because there is no error message:

```
import turtle
import random

# create sprite
class Sprite(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, sprite_shape, color, startx, starty):
        super().__init__( shape=sprite_shape)

        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.goto(startx, starty)

        self.speed = 1

    def move(self):
        self.forward(self.speed)

        # Boundary detection
        if self.xcor() > 300:
            self.setx(300)
            self.rt(90)
        elif self.xcor() < -300:
            self.setx(-300)
            self.lt(120)

        if self.ycor() > 300:
            self.sety(300)
            self.lt(90)
        elif self.ycor() < -300:
            self.sety(-300)
            self.lt(120)


    def is_collision(self, other):
        return self.distance(other) < 20

# create enemy
class Enemy(Sprite):
    def __init__(self ,  spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        Sprite.__init__(self  , spriteshape, color, startx, starty)
        self.speed = 4
        self.setheading(random.randint(0,360))  

#Set up the screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")

#Draw border
border_pen = turtle.Turtle()
border_pen.speed(0)
border_pen.color("white")
border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-300,-300)
border_pen.pendown()
border_pen.pensize(6)
border_pen.fd(600)
border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.fd(600)
border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.fd(600)
border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.fd(600)
border_pen.lt(90)
border_pen.hideturtle()

#create the base
base = turtle.Turtle()
base.speed(0)
base.color("blue")
base.penup()
base.setposition(0, -280)
base.pendown()
base.pensize(3)
base.forward(295)
base.right(90)
base.forward(15)
base.right(90)
base.forward(592)
base.right(90)
base.forward(15)
base.right(90)
base.forward(390)
base.hideturtle()


#Create the player turtle
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("yellow")
player.shape("square")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.setheading(90)
player.shapesize(2.5)

playerspeed = 15






#Create the player turtle

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("yellow")
player.shape("square")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.shapesize(2.3)

player_speed = 35

# player movement

def move_left():
    x = player.xcor() - player_speed

    if x < -280:
        x = - 280

    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor() + player_speed

    if x > 280:
        x = 280

    player.setx(x)


# keybindings
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")

# create sprite
enemy = Enemy('circle', 'red', -200, 250)

# main game loop
def play():
    enemy.move()

    # check for collision
    if enemy.is_collision(player):
         x = random.randint(-250, 250)
         y = random.randint(-250, 250)
         enemy.setposition(-250, 250)
         enemy.setheading(250)

         wn.ontimer(play, 10 )

play()


if enemy.is_collision(base):
    player.hideturtle()
    enemy.hideturtle()
    base.hideturtle()
    print ("Game Over")


play()
```

I would expect the enemy to move but it's frozen mid-air. Player moves but leaves a duplicate behind. I can't test if the respawn system works after collision with the base.

Comment: Hi perhaps step through with the debugger to see where it fails?

Comment: if you don't know how to use debuger then add more `print()` to see which part is executed and when it stops.

Comment: I'm looking up how to use debugger right now

Comment: when I run code then it doesn't freeze - it only ends its work and it exit without closing window. Probably you may need `turtle.mainloop()` to run it.

Comment: When I add `turtle.mainloop()` at the end then I can move yellow square using arrow keys.

Comment: ohh ok i just used debugger and this what came up

Comment: (line;import os) is what the error and its highlights that line

Comment: turtle.mainloop() would the move the player but still leave a cast behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reworked your code below, addressing several problems and style issues.  The major problems I noted: you confused collision with the shape *drawn by* the `base` turtle with collision *with* the `base` turtle; in `Sprite`, you redefined turtle's `speed()` method to be a instance variable; those issues addressed by @furas (+1) though `play()` needed `ontimer()` in an `else` clause for the game to exit properly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 600
MARGIN = 50
BASE_HEIGHT = 15
PEN_SIZE = 5
PLAYER_SIZE = 50
SPRITE_SIZE = CURSOR_SIZE

PLAYER_SPEED = PLAYER_SIZE/2
ENEMY_SPEED = SPRITE_SIZE/4

# Create sprite
class Sprite(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, sprite_shape, color, startx, starty):
        super().__init__(shape=sprite_shape)
        self.hideturtle()

        self.speed('fastest')
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.goto(startx, starty)

        self.showturtle()

        self.steps = 1

    def move(self):
        self.forward(self.steps)

        # Boundary detection
        if self.xcor() > WIDTH/2 - SPRITE_SIZE/2:
            self.setx(WIDTH/2 - SPRITE_SIZE/2)
            self.rt(90)
        elif self.xcor() < SPRITE_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2:
            self.setx(SPRITE_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2)
            self.lt(120)

        if self.ycor() > HEIGHT/2 - SPRITE_SIZE/2:
            self.sety(HEIGHT/2 - SPRITE_SIZE/2)
            self.lt(90)
        elif self.ycor() < SPRITE_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2:
            self.sety(SPRITE_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2)
            self.lt(120)

    def is_collision(self, other):
        return self.distance(other) < SPRITE_SIZE/2

# Create enemy
class Enemy(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        super().__init__(spriteshape, color, startx, starty)
        self.steps = ENEMY_SPEED
        self.setheading(randint(0, 360))

    def is_collision(self, other):
        return self.distance(other) < PLAYER_SIZE/2

# Set up the screen
wn = Screen()
wn.setup(WIDTH + MARGIN * 2, HEIGHT + MARGIN * 2)
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.title("Space Invaders")

# Draw border
border_pen = Turtle()
border_pen.hideturtle()
border_pen.speed('fastest')
border_pen.color('white')
border_pen.pensize(PEN_SIZE)

border_pen.penup()
border_pen.setposition(-WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/2)
border_pen.pendown()

for _ in range(2):
    border_pen.fd(WIDTH)
    border_pen.lt(90)
    border_pen.fd(HEIGHT)
    border_pen.lt(90)

# Create the base
base = Turtle()
base.hideturtle()
base.shape('square')
base.color('blue', 'black')
base.penup()
base.setposition(0, BASE_HEIGHT/2 - HEIGHT/2 + PEN_SIZE)
base.shapesize(BASE_HEIGHT / CURSOR_SIZE, (WIDTH - PEN_SIZE*2) / CURSOR_SIZE, PEN_SIZE)
base.showturtle()

# Create the player turtle
player = Turtle()
player.hideturtle()
player.shape('square')
player.shapesize(PLAYER_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
player.color('yellow')
player.speed('fastest')
player.penup()
player.setposition(0, PLAYER_SIZE/2 - HEIGHT/2 + BASE_HEIGHT + PEN_SIZE)
player.setheading(90)
player.showturtle()

# player movement

def move_left():
    x = player.xcor() - PLAYER_SPEED

    if x < PLAYER_SIZE - WIDTH/2:
        x = PLAYER_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2

    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor() + PLAYER_SPEED

    if x > WIDTH/2 - PLAYER_SIZE:
        x = WIDTH/2 - PLAYER_SIZE/2

    player.setx(x)

# Keybindings
wn.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
wn.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
wn.listen()

# Create sprite
enemy = Enemy('circle', 'red', randint(SPRITE_SIZE - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - SPRITE_SIZE), randint(0, HEIGHT/2 - SPRITE_SIZE))

# main game loop
def play():
    enemy.move()

    # check for collision
    if enemy.is_collision(player):
        x = randint(SPRITE_SIZE - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - SPRITE_SIZE)
        y = randint(0, HEIGHT/2 - SPRITE_SIZE)
        enemy.setposition(x, y)
        enemy.setheading(randint(0, 360))

    if enemy.ycor() <= BASE_HEIGHT - HEIGHT/2 + SPRITE_SIZE/2:
        player.hideturtle()
        enemy.hideturtle()
        base.hideturtle()
        print("Game Over")
    else:
        wn.ontimer(play, 25)

# start
play()
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems

1. you need `mainloop()` so turtle (or rather `tkinter` used by turtle) could run loop which get key/mouse events from system (again and again) and run listener. It also use this loop to run elements added with `timer()`.
2. you have wrong indentions in line with `wn.ontimer(play, 10)`. You have to use it at the end of `play()` to run it again but you have it inside `if enemy.is_collision(player):` so it is not executed.

Code which moves red circle and I can use keys to move yellow square

```
# main game loop
def play():
    enemy.move()

    # check for collision
    if enemy.is_collision(player):
         x = random.randint(-250, 250)
         y = random.randint(-250, 250)
         enemy.setposition(-250, 250)
         enemy.setheading(250)

    if enemy.is_collision(base):
        player.hideturtle()
        enemy.hideturtle()
        base.hideturtle()
        print ("Game Over")

    wn.ontimer(play, 10)

# start
play()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: the collision system between the base the and the player still leaves a cast..debugger highlights  import os at the very top

Comment: do you run it in any IDE/Editor ? Then run it without IDE/Editor and don't bother this highlights. This code doesn't need `import os`.

Comment: IDLE is only tool to create script but later normally script is used without IDLE. Tools also may have mistakes and sometimes it is good to run code without IDLE to see if problem is in script or in IDLE.

Comment: I tried pycharm and enemy moves but doesn't interact with the base. The  player still leaves a copy in the middle while moving

Comment: see your code - you create `player` two times so you have two yellow squares on screen.

Comment: as for interact with base: you use `self.distance(other)` for check collision so use `print(self.distance(other))` to see what values you get. Maybe they are never smaller then 20. Your base is only 15 height - maybe if you use heigher then it will work. Or maybe you have to use different method to check collision. As for me turtle is good for drawing figures but not for games. I would use `Pygame` for this.